# java properties do not load inputstream for same stream again

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to load a properties file and read values for given keys in the properties file. Properties file looks like :

```
text.properties 
A=Z
B=Y
C=X

public class TestStreams {
static String path = "test.properties";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    TestStreams test = new TestStreams();
    InputStream stream =  new FileInputStream(new File(path));

    System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "A"));
    System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "B"));
    System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "C"));
}

public String getValue(InputStream stream, String key) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    String value = null;
    try {
        props.load(stream);
        value = props.getProperty(key);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
   }
}

Output : 
Z
null
null
```

I tried debugging, for first print statement at props.load loads all the 3 properties into props, but for second and third print statement props.load loads zero properties into props.

Comment: The first props.load(stream) is going to read the entire contents of the file into the properties object and hit the end of the file so for your first getValue that properties object will have "A", "B", and "C".  Since the properties object isn't returned it gets garbage collected.  The next call to getValue creates a new Properties object but since the stream has already reached the end of the file nothing is left to read into it (and same for the next any future calls to getValue).

Comment: And why would you do this anyway, instead of conserving the `Properties` object?

Answer (score 1):

The provided stream is at its end position after `props.load`, so there is nothing more it could read.

You can either re-open the stream before each invocation or (better) only load the properties once and reuse the `Properties` instance:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestStreams {
    static String path = "test.properties";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TestStreams test = new TestStreams();
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));

        System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "A"));
        System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "B"));
        System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "C"));

        // Variant 1
        stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "A"));
        stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "B"));
        stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        System.out.println(test.getValue(stream, "C"));

        // Variant 2
        stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(stream);
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("A"));
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("B"));
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("C"));
    }

    public String getValue(InputStream stream, String key) throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        String value = null;
        try {
            props.load(stream);
            value = props.getProperty(key);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

As a side note, you should use the [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to make sure your stream is closed afterwards:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));) {
    props.load(stream);
}
System.out.println(props.getProperty("A"));
System.out.println(props.getProperty("B"));
System.out.println(props.getProperty("C"));
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first time you read in the properties file, the `FileInputStream` reached its end and subsequent reads will lead to no data, leaving the new `Properties` instance empty. You have to create a new `FileInputStream` or (better) do the reading and creation of the `Properties` once and use that for the `getValue`-calls.